# How to add a new value to a list with md-autocomplete?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to use `md-autocomplete` to search for an object in an array. If the object is found I want an edit form to be populated, but if the object is not found, I want the user to be able to add a new one using the same form.

For example, I have an array of contacts: `[{name: string, email: string}...]`.

Then in my template:

```
<md-autocomplete       
  md-selected-item="$ctrl.newContact"
  md-search-text="$ctrl.searchString"
  md-selected-item-change="$ctrl.selectedItemChanged(item)"
  md-items="item in $ctrl.getContactsByFullName($ctrl.searchString)"
  md-floating-label="Contact's Name"
  md-item-text="item.fullName">
</md-autocomplete>
<md-input-container>
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type='email' ng-model='$ctrl.newContact.email/>
</md-input-container>
```

When I enter a new value in `Contact's name`, tab to email and enter a value in email, the value of  `$ctrl.newContact.fullName` becomes an object.

What am I doing wrong here? I've fiddled and codepenned but can't seem to get it right. Does anybody have a working example please?

Answer (score -1):

Why not use md-search-text value inside the controller, then do with the value whatever you desire...Something like:

```
  md-search-text="searchString"
```

Ctrl:

```
console.log($scope.searchString);
//You can do with the value whatever you want!
```

Not sure if thats what you needed...

Answer (score -2):

I made a simple example.

https://jsfiddle.net/relferreira/faqsg514/1/

What you did wrong is that you defined the selected item as `$ctrl.newContact`, been each item an `Object`.

**Controller**:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);

angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainCtrl', mainCtrl);

 function mainCtrl(){
    var vm = this;
  vm.newContact = {};
  vm.searchString = '';
  vm.selectedItemChanged = selectedItemChanged;
  vm.getContactsByFullName = getContactsByFullName;

  vm.contacts = [
    {name: 'Renan', email:'asldfk@.com'},
    {name: 'Renan', email:'asldfk@.com'},
    {name: 'Renan', email:'asldfk@.com'}
  ];

  function selectedItemChanged(){
    vm.newContact.fullName = vm.selectedContact.name;
  }

  function getContactsByFullName(name){
    return vm.contacts;
  }
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app">

  <div data-ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainVm">
    {{mainVm.newContact}}
    <md-autocomplete       
      md-selected-item="mainVm.selectedContact"
      md-search-text="mainVm.searchString"
      md-selected-item-change="mainVm.selectedItemChanged()"
      md-items="item in mainVm.getContactsByFullName($ctrl.searchString)"
      md-floating-label="Contact's Name"
      md-item-text="item.name">
        <md-item-template>
          <span md-highlight-text="mainVm.searchString">{{item.name}}</span>
      </md-item-template>
      </md-autocomplete>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type='email' data-ng-model="mainVm.newContact.email"/>
      </md-input-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Example does not work. I used the fiddle in this post and typed in Edward and the name stayed as Renan.

Answer (score -2):

for those who are looking to achieve the same check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7tv2x9p/)

**Approach:**
Basically it attach a new model whenever `md-search-text-change` event occured and also remove the garbage model.

**html code**

```
<md-autocomplete 
...
md-search-text="searchString"
md-search-text-change="selectedItemChanged(searchString)
...
</md-autocomplete>
```

**angular code**

```
function selectedItemChanged(searchString){
  vm.contactArray.splice(actualLength,currentLength-actualLength)
  vm.newModel = {};
  vm.newModel.name=searchString;
  vm.newModel.email='test'
  vm.contacts.push(vm.newModel)

}
```

Comment: instead of downvoting can you please come and tell what's wrong with this approach so that we all can learn the right way

Comment: Well, first of all. What's `actualLength` and `currentLength`? Second of all, why are you splicing `contactArray` and then pushing to the `contacts` array?